# Move and shrink a partition at the same time

Tags: filesystems, partition, dd, parted, move-partition

It is possible to shrink a partition with, for example, `parted`.

It is also possible to move (copy) a partition from one hard drive to another, by creating a partition of the same size on the target drive and then do something like `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1`.

Is it possible to do this simultaneously?
To shrink a not very full partition of drive a and copy it smaller on drive b.
Of course one could shrink it on drive a first, but I think it should be possible without doing that first.

Answer (score 2):

"shrinking" is something you do to a *file system*, moving partions is what you do to a *partition*; these are two independent things, and no, usually moving and shrinking can't be combined (at least I'm not aware of any file system that has a shrinking tool that copies).

Also, it makes no sense to *want* to do it: instead, simply make a new file system on the target of the size you want, and copy the files from the source to the target. That's pretty much what you want to achieve, anyways, but with less work, and afterwards, probably better structured, less fragmented storage layout.

Comment: Good point. shrinking is for the filesystem and copying for the partition. How does one copy all the contents of a filesystem including `symbolic links`, `a-time`, and do I know what I am forgetting here?

Comment: With `cp`! Use the `-a` option (`-a` is short for `--archive`), which recursively copies everything, keeps owenrships, permissions, dates, extended attributes, links and basically everything intact.

Comment: Does this work for all filesystems? e.g. `ntfs` as well?

Comment: yes, that's the thing about file systems: they abstract their own structure so that tools like `cp` can just copy files and their attributes.